# Получение данных, отправляемых POST в виде json

Tags: php, json, post, яндекс-маркет

API яндекса говорит о том, что по некому урл, который Я укажу уйдет пост в json, на который Я должен дать ответ

```
https://tech.yandex.ru/market/partner/doc/dg/reference/post-cart-docpage/#output_1
```

Если Я просто в файле для проверки делаю так:

```
    $responseJson = '[
{  
"cart":  {    
"currency":"RUR",     
"items":    
[   
{
    "feedId":12345, 
    "offerId":"49", 
    "offerName":"Чайник электрический 100W", 
    "count":1, 
    "feedCategoryId":"35"
},    
{
    "feedId":12346, 
    "offerId":"71", 
    "offerName":"Тостер", 
    "count":1, 
    "feedCategoryId":"35"
}     
],     

"delivery":     
{
    "region":       
    {
        "id":213, 
        "name":"Москва", 
        "type":"CITY", 
        "parent":          
        {
            "id":1, 
            "name":"Москва и Московская область", 
            "type":"SUBJECT_FEDERATION", 
            "parent":             
            {
                "id":3, 
                "name":"Центр", 
                "type":"COUNTRY_DISTRICT", 
                "parent":                
                {
                    "id":225, 
                    "name":"Россия", 
                    "type":"COUNTRY"
                }             
            }          
        }        
    },     

    "address":
    {
        "country":"Россия", 
        "postcode":"119313", 
        "city":"Москва", 
        "subway":"Проспект Вернадского", 
        "street":"Ленинский проспект", 
        "house":"90", "floor":"6"
    }    
}  
}
}
]'; // ваш пример строки
header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');
header('Accept: application/json');
$response = json_decode($responseJson, true); // преобразование строки в формате json в ассоциативный массив 
$currency = $response[0]['cart']['currency']; // ваш искомая валюта
echo $currency; //выводим валюту
```

То вся игра идет хорошо. 
Если пытаюсь получить json через POST вот так: `$responseJson = $_POST['cart'];`, то ничего не выходит. Пусто.
Я не верно получаю json данные?

Comment: А, метод POST это вроде отправка данных а не получение пробуйте методом GET.

Comment: К сожалению, тоже ничего не приносит. попытка разложить $_POST и $_GET не увенчается успехом. Раскладываю:  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {отправка на майл значений} массивы пусты(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ПХП по умолчанию не парсит запросы кроме `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`  `multipart/form-data`. Т.е. тельце надо парсить самому.

Можно проверить что бы `$_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"] ==  'application/json'` до и что значение `json_decode` не `NULL` после.

А тело парсится так:

```
<?php

$postData = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($postData, true);

var_dump($data["cart"]);
```

Кстати ещё как дополнение: 
ПХП не парсит PUT/DELETE... запросы.

Функция что бы парсить для `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`  `multipart/form-data` http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php,
а  для `application/json` как и в предидущем примере `json_decode`.

```
$postData = file_get_contents('php://input');

// `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`  `multipart/form-data`
$data = parse_str($postData);
// or
// `application/json`
$data = json_decode($postData, true);

var_dump($data);
```

Comment: поклон в ноги. оно.  Кому то понадобится $responseJson_str = file_get_contents('php://input');
$responseJson = '[' . $responseJson_str . ']';
$response = json_decode($responseJson, true); // преобразование строки в формате json в ассоциативный массив 
$currency = $response[0]['currency']; // ваш искомая валюта

Comment: Да, не за что. Добавил ещё информацию.

Answer (score 0):

Банальный `$_REQUEST` будет работать без `file_get_contents`.

Comment: в таком случае полезно наверное пример предоставить как получить данные таким способом.