# ошибка при передаче переменных post через ajax не выполняется

Tags: php, ajax

отсылаю через ajax данные

```
$( "#reg" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var $form = $( this );
    var $email = $form.find( "input[name='email']" ).val();
    var $name = $form.find( "input[name='name']" ).val();
    var $surname = $form.find( "input[name='surname']" ).val();
    var $password = $form.find( "input[name='password']" ).val();
    var $url = $form.attr( "action" ); 
  var posting = $.post( $url, {
   email: $email,
   name: $name,
   surname: $surname,
   password: $password
  } );
  posting.done(function( data ) {
    $(".session").text(data);
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

не выполняется условие в php, хотя в форме все было заполненно

```
if (isset($_POST['email']) &&
isset($_POST['password']) &&
isset($_POST['name']) &&
isset($_POST['surname']) )
```

Comment: скриншот консоли в момент передачи покажите плииз, чтоб убедиться что данные действительно передаются......а вообще можно без `isset` писать, вроде.......и то, что после `if` можете написать.

Comment: Думаю что проблема вот в чем:  http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496065/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85-post-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5-json/496348#496348

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вот еще часть php кода: `else print_r("false");` выводит false

Comment: в качестве совета, вместо использования `form.find("input[name='email'"])` добавьте лучше уникальные идентификаторы к инпутам вида `id="email"` и пользуйте `$("#email").val()`, а то куча усложненного кода. + вместо отдельной переменной для каждого поля можно сразу все собирать в объект, который в дальнейшем отправить на сервер.

Comment: @Nikolay а скрин консоли?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский выводит false, все

Comment: @Nikolay какой еще false? `скриншот консоли в момент передачи` ......в смысле вкладка Network... form data..... и подобная лабуда

Comment: @Nikolay, сделайте так: `var dataToSend = {email: $email, ...}; console.log(dataToSend); var posting = $.post($url, dataToSend);` и поделитесь с нами содержимым консоли браузера.

Comment: в chrome network в headers в Form Data передается
"email:123@mail.ru
name:Василий
surname:Федоров
password:424324". Если это имелось ввиду

Comment: @Igor при выполнении скрипта выводится тоже самое

Comment: Вы пробовали `var_dump($_POST)`? Если пусто то перечитайте ответ с моей ссылки.

Comment: @E_p пробовал( ничего не выводит..

Comment: Я вам скинул ссылку на решение. PHP сам непарсит json  параметры!!!

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496065/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85-post-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5-json/496348

Comment: @E_p это не ответ. У меня вид запроса `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, который как раз парсится через php