# Как обработать Javascript-объект (невалидный JSON) в PHP?

Tags: php, json, api

Возникла проблема - API отдаёт данные в JSON формате, примерно в таком виде:

```
{
  messages: [
    {
      channel: "79991234567",
      phone: "79117777777",
      dateTime: 1544844684000,
      type: 1,
      status: 99,
      text: "Добрый день"
    }, {
      channel: "79991234567",
      phone: "79117777777",
      dateTime: 1544849654000,
      type: 5,
      status: 2,
      text: "",
      content: "https://app.wazzup24.com/api/v1/store/07146d53b21e4a41aca49b6bc2391c7e8100b6dac6df"
    }
  ],
  statuses: [
    {
      messageId: "7271506a-1959-4e39-acaf-2ccc19d77ef2",
      status: 3
    }
  ],
  channels: [
    {
      channel: "79991234567",
      state: "active"
    }
  ]
}
```

Полученные данные нужно обработать через PHP и я пробовал сделать это через json_decode, но эта функция не возвращала никаких данных. После некоторого поиска и просмотра примеров, я понял, что причина скорее всего в том, что это JS-объект, но он не валиден как JSON, т.к. ключи и некоторые свойства не обёрнуты в кавычки. Можно ли как-то еще решить эту проблему?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Проблема только в обёрнутости свойств? Никакой мути типа undefined, дат и js-кода в значениях нет? Кавычки у значений всегда двойные? Одинарных или косых нет?

Comment: а что за api если не секрет? Данные оттуда получаются сразу через php или вначале на клиенте на js и с клиента отдаются на сервер?

Comment: По поводу проблемы: предполагаю, что да, это пример из документации, реальные данные, пока не смог получить, из-за проблемы с обработкой.

Comment: А по поводу API: не совсем даже API, это приходит веб-хук с сервиса https://wazzup24.com/

Comment: @yurwd так в итоге Данные оттуда получаются сразу через php или вначале на клиенте на js и с клиента отдаются на сервер? Ну или планируется как? Потому что в зависимости от этого и ответ может быть разным

Comment: На сколько я понял - то, что указано на странице с примерами - это то, что надо отсылать, а не получать. А для получения там указано, что `В заголовках запроса необходимо указывать «Content-type» = «application/json»`. В итоге валидный json и придет

Comment: Я ответ исправил.

Comment: @Qwertiy если использовать javascript для этой цели - то операции в ответе бессмысленные)) Потому что там регулярка не нужна. А в целом, если взглянуть на приведённую автором ссылку, то те данные, что он привел - это, наоборот, исходящие данные, а не получаемые (если я правильно понял смысл строк на той самой странице). А для получения валидного json там просто надо указать content-type

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Сервис передает эти данные к PHP-скрипту через POST-запрос при наступлении определенного события. Возможности настроить в сервисе заголовки или что-либо еще, к сожалению нет, приходится работать с тем, что приходит в PHP скрипт. Проще говоря, это именно то, что всё-таки нужно получать.

Comment: Попробую с регулярным выражением, спасибо.

Comment: @СергейМишин, php тоже умеет регулярку. Хочешь сказать, замену, как у меня в ответе, на php сделать не получится?

Comment: @Qwertiy ты не так прочитал мой комментарий. Я написал, что для перевода представленных данных в json используя javascript - регулярки не нужны.

Comment: @СергейМишин, да, на js не нужны, но у вопроса тег php. Я по идее под него регулярку писал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> #### ОТВЕТ СОДЕРЖИТ ОШИБКУ
>
> В массивах строками становятся числа (а отрицательные вообще всё ломают), null и true/false.

Если разница по сравнению с json'ом только в том, что часть ключей написаны без кавычек, а [всё остальное](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/439183/178988) соответствует формату JSON, то это легко исправляется заменой по регулярному выражению `(?:"((?:\\.|.)*)"|([.\w]+))(\s*:\s*(?:[[{]|"(?:\\.|.)*"|[-.\w]+))?` на `"$1$2"$3`.

Вот пример на JS:

```js
var str = document.querySelector('textarea').value
var json = str.replace(/(?:"((?:\\.|.)*)"|([.\w]+))(\s*:\s*(?:[[{]|"(?:\\.|.)*"|[-.\w]+))?/g, '"$1$2"$3')
console.log(JSON.parse(json))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

```html
<textarea>{
  messages: [
    {
      channel: "79991234567",
      phone: "79117777777",
      dateTime: 1544844684000,
      type: 1,
      status: 99,
      text: "Добрый день"
    }, {
      channel: "79991234567",
      phone: "79117777777",
      dateTime: 1544849654000,
      type: 5,
      status: 2,
      text: "",
      content: "https://app.wazzup24.com/api/v1/store/07146d53b21e4a41aca49b6bc2391c7e8100b6dac6df"
    }
  ],
  statuses: [
    {
      messageId: "7271506a-1959-4e39-acaf-2ccc19d77ef2",
      status: 3
    }
  ],
  channels: [
    {
      channel: "79991234567",
      state: "active"
    }
  ]
}</textarea>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ с, пробовал реализовать через preg_replace, частично получилось, только во вложенных массивах не заменялись значения. Думаю, это можно было доработать, но уже не стал, т.к. проблема решилась иначе. В любом случае спасибо за наводку.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решена, всем спасибо за ответы. При дальнейших поисках оказалось, что я был неправ: проблема не в том, что названия не обёрнуты в кавычки, а в том, что, как я узнал, PHP по умолчанию не парсит запросы кроме application/x-www-form-urlencoded multipart/form-data. В моем случае отправлялся запрос application/json и когда я пытался, получить к нему доступ из массива $_POST возвращался пустой массив.

Помогло решение от @E_p (из вопроса [Получение данных, отправляемых POST в виде json](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496065/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85-post-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5-json)):

```
$postData = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($postData, true);
```

В моем случае это сработало.
Еще раз спасибо всем за участие!