# Как принять POST json запрос на php?

Tags: php, json, post, api

Всем привет! Возник вопрос, с которым мучаюсь уже несколько дней.

Имеется сервис, который отправляет на указанную страницу POST запрос в формате json, мне же нужно его поймать на своей странице и добавить элементы в базу.

Пример запроса:

```
POST /page.php HTTP/1.1
Host: host.host
Authorization: Bearer XXXXX
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{
"date": "2017-04-25T01:29:20.4520214+00:00",
"stocks": [
    {
    "nnt": 111173,
    "qnt": 5,
    "man": "man",
    "prcRet": 117.99,
    "name": "name",
    "dtComing": "2017-08-09T00:00:00 + 07:00"
    }
 ]
}
```

Пример успешного ответа:

```
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
[]
```

Пытаюсь поймать через php

```
$v = json_decode(stripslashes(file_get_contents("php://input")));
echo json_encode($v);
```

Но на странице получаю **NULL**, хотя сервис говорит, что все гуд. Подскажите пожалуйста, как поймать этот json?

Comment: 1. удалить stripslashes 2. если не получится, смотреть какая ошибка, для этого есть [json_last_error()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-last-error.php)

Comment: [Получение данных, отправляемых POST в виде json](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496065/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85-post-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5-json)

Comment: почитал, попробовал написал так, как получилось у пользователя по ссылке выше: 
`<?
header('Content-Type: application/json;');
$responseJson_str = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
$responseJson = '[' . $responseJson_str . ']'; 
$response = json_decode($responseJson, true); 
?>`
Сервис ответил, что все "ОК", но я получил в итоге пустой массив...