# Вопрос по xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, php

Есть код такого формата (просто для теста):

```
let gus = 'stroka1';

    function send_data (data){

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/add-session.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    let json = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(json)

    xhr.send(json);
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status != 200) { // анализируем HTTP-статус ответа, если статус не 200, то произошла ошибка
            alert(`Ошибка ${xhr.status}: ${xhr.statusText}`); // Например, 404: Not Found
        } else { // если всё прошло гладко, выводим результат
            alert(`Готово, получили ${xhr.response.length} байт`); // response -- это ответ сервера
         }
        };

    };

send_data(gus);
```

Как мне принять данные в `add-session.php`?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/496348

Comment: Огромное спасибо!
Но после использования примера для application/json PHP говорит, что ему приходит NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как получить `POST JSON` в PHP:

```
function get_json(){
    $postData = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $data = json_decode($postData, true);
    var_dump($postData, $data);
}
```

Или же если отправили через `$_POST`, то соответственно можно его получить так же и на сервере:

```
function get_json(){
    $data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Adelineoff пожалуйста! Обращайтесь.