# Почему массив POST всегда пустой?

Tags: php

Использую php скрипт для обработки запросов с **IOS** приложения. Но мой **POST-массив** всегда пустой. Пытался изначально тестить скрипт через Postman, в этом случае массив post также всегда был пуст. Думал, что ошибка в самом **postman**, но когда руки дошли до написания кода **swift** и отправки запроса на сервер, понял, что ошибка на серверной стороне.

Вот мой код:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$response = array();

if(isset($_POST) and count($_POST)){

    if($_POST['web_pass'] == WEB_PASS){
        $response['error']=false;
        $response['message']='Auth complete successful';
    }else{
        $response['error']=true;
        $response['message']='Error - 1: Wrong pass auth';
    }

}else{
    $response['error']=true;
    $response['message']='Вы не авторизированы';
}

print_r(json_encode($response));
```

Ответ от сервера всегда **"Вы не авторизированы"**
Возможно, ошибки в настройке сервера, но в других модулях все работает.

---

Дополнительно:

Код на стороне swift:

```
let data = [ "web_pass" : httpREQ.web_pass ] as [String : Any]

            AF.request(httpREQ.URL, method: .post, parameters: data, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).validate(statusCode: 200 ..< 500).responseString { AFdata in
                do {
        
                    guard let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: AFdata.data!) as? [String: Any] else {
                        print("Error: Cannot convert data to JSON object")
                        return
                    }
                    guard let prettyJsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: .prettyPrinted) else {
                        print("Error: Cannot convert JSON object to Pretty JSON data")
                        return
                    }
                    guard let prettyPrintedJson = String(data: prettyJsonData, encoding: .utf8) else {
                        print("Error: Could print JSON in String")
                        return
                    }
                    
                    print(prettyPrintedJson)
                } catch {
                    print("Error: Trying to convert JSON data to string")
                    return
                }
            }
```

Comment: Ну вы б хоть показали что отправляете

Comment: json_encode($_POST) тоже пуст?

Comment: @ВадимАлександру, все верно, закодированный POST также пуст.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, отредактировал вопрос. Я пока отправляю лишь параметр ```web_pass``` дабы наладить работу с сервером.

Comment: Покажите что и как отправляете. Может вы банально Content-Type ставите неправильно. А $_POST собирается только для двух весьма конкретных типов данных: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: @Мелкий, отредактировал вопрос.

Comment: @Kirzzz, попробуйте так: `var_dump(file_get_contents('php //input'));`

Comment: @Node_pro, массив POST все также пуст, уже не знаю в чем проблема даже...

Comment: Я свифт не знаю, но `encoding: JSONEncoding.default` не похож ни на `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` ни на `multipart/form-data`, а PHP умеет разбирать только эти `Content-Type` https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: @Kirzzz, а что моя запись возвращает? Она должна возвращать POST. Если все-же нет. Посмотрите нет случайно у вас переадресации

Comment: PHP разбирает тело запроса на основе content-type. В начало скрипта вставьте `var_dump(getallheaders()); die;`, весь вывод - сюда. Так мы поймем какие заголовки пришли.

Comment: @TotalPusher, "array(10) {  ["Host"]=>  string(10) "desavir.ru"  ["X-Forwarded-Proto"]=>  string(5) "https"  ["X-Forwarded-Port"]=>  string(3) "443"  ["Connection"]=>  string(5) "close"  ["Content-Length"]=>  string(3) "203"  ["Content-Type"]=>  string(16) "application/json"  ["Accept"]=>  string(3) "*/*"  ["User-Agent"]=>  string(65) "Desavir/1.0 (Kirzzz.Desavir; build:1; iOS 13.7.0) Alamofire/5.2.2"  ["Accept-Language"]=>  string(21) "en;q=1.0, ru-RU;q=0.9"  ["Accept-Encoding"]=>  string(35) "br;q=1.0, gzip;q=0.9, deflate;q=0.8"}null")

Comment: `["Content-Type"]=> string(16) "application/json"` - значит пых не будет преобразовать в массив POST. Используйте `var_dump(file_get_contents('php //input'));` как вам подсказали выше. Или меняйте этот заголовок и структуру тела запроса.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496065/Получение-данных-отправляемых-post-в-виде-json