# fetch: до сервера не доходят POST запросы

Tags: javascript, post, fetch

ситуация следующая:

посылаю на сервер POST запрос с использованием функционала `fetch`:

```
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method:         'POST',
    headers:        {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body:           JSON.stringify({"request": "data"}) 
  });
```

и сервер не получает POST запроса (сделал проверку - чтобы сервер присылал то, что получил (`$_POST`)

при этом если посылать GET запрос

```
  const response = await fetch("url?request=data", {
    method:         'GET',
  });
```

то сервер все нормально получает и возвращает (возвращает `$_GET` соответственно)

подскажите в чем может быть дело и куда смотреть?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496065

Comment: @andreymal, огромное спасибо, совет очень помог