# отправка данных JSON api на сервер(js, php)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Необходимо достать из Api часть данных при нажатии на кнопки для дальнейшей отправки в базу данных.

Завис на моменте преобразования json для отправки на сервер, вот что получилось на данный момент:

```
  button id='button'
Кнопка
  /button

//js
  $(document).on('click', '#button', function(){



    async function getResponse(){
    let response = await fetch('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/global')
    let content = await response.json()
    let total = content.data.market_cap_percentage
    let  totalT =   JSON.stringify(total);
    console.log(totalT);
    getResponse();

      $.ajax({
      url: 'config.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
          func: 'func_data',
          name: totalT,
      },
      success: function(data){
        $('p.out').text(data.name);
      }, error: function(){
        console.log('ERROR');
      }
    })
});

//php
$func = $_POST['func'];
if ($func === 'func_data') {
    $arr['name'] = $_POST['name'];
    echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

Comment: Если вы используете `JSON.stringify` то на сервере надо писать json_**de**code. Причём у той переменной, которую и преобразовывали, т.е. у `name`

Comment: Не путайте данные формы в $_POST, и JSON строку. В первом случае вы можете получить доступ к переменным в массиве $_POST, во втором вам нужно взять строку из [php://input](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496065/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85-post-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5-json), либо $_REQUEST, и используя json_decode декодировать её.