# При отправке формы переменной присваивается NULL

Tags: javascript, php, html

После ввода в форму php выдаёт переменную $login: NULL

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Цветучено</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/css.css">
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" method="POST" class="form_div">
        <h1 class="header">Авторизация</h1>
    <div class="div-login">
        <p class="login_header">Логин:</p>
        <input type="text" class="login_input" name="login_input" autocomplete="username">
    </div>
    <div class="div-password">
        <p class="password_header">Пароль:</p>
        <input type="password" class="password_input" name="password_input" autocomplete="current-password"><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="div-button">
        <button type="submit" class="login-btn">Вход</button>
        <button type="submit" class="register-btn"><a href="register.php">Регистрация</a></button>
    </div>

    <p class="msg none"></p>
</form>   
<script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

```
<?php
    require_once 'connect.php';

    $login = $_POST['login_input'];
    $password = $_POST['password_input'];

    $error_fields = [];

    if ($login === '') {
        $error_fields[] = 'login';
    }

    if ($password === '') {
        $error_fields[] = 'password';
    }

    if (!empty($error_fields)) {
        $response = [
            "status" => false,
            "type" => 1,
            "message" => "Проверьте правильность полей",
            "fields" => $error_fields
        ];

        echo json_encode($response);

        die();
    }

    $password = md5($password);

    $check_user = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$login' AND `password` = '$password'");
    $check_user_row = $check_user->fetchColumn();
    if ($check_user_row > 0) {

        // $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check_user);

        // $_SESSION['user'] = [
        //     "id" => $user['id'],
        //     "full_name" => $user['name']
        // ];

        $response = [
            "status" => true
        ];

        echo json_encode($response);

    } else {

        $response = [
            "status" => false,
            "message" => 'Не верный логин или пароль',
            "check" => $check_user,
            "login" => $login
        ];

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
?>
```

```
/*
    Авторизация
 */
$('.login-btn').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $(`input`).removeClass('error');

  let login = $('input[name="login_input"]').val(),
      password = $('input[name="password_input"]').val();

  $.ajax({
      url: 'vendor/singin.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
          login: login,
          password: password
      },
      success (data) {

          if (data.status) {
              document.location.href = 'index.php';
          } else {
              if (data.type === 1) {
                  data.fields.forEach(function (field) {
                      $(`input[name="${field}"]`).addClass('error');
                  });
              }

              $('.msg').removeClass('none').text(data.message);
          }

      }
  });

});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вы скриптом отправляете данные:

```
data: {
  login: login,
  password: password
}
```

А принимаете их ключами с html атрибута name

```
$login = $_POST['login_input'];
$password = $_POST['password_input'];
```

То есть, у вас и пароль и логин null, а вы в проверках сравниваете их со строками и ничего не работает как положено. Используйте empty()

***upd.*** никогда напрямую не используйте значение с инпутов в запросах, их нужно, хотя бы минимально, валидировать, убирать лишнее и т.п. - прочтите [Защита от SQL-инъекций в PHP и MySQL](https://habr.com/ru/post/148701/)

Comment: А как использовать значения запрос?

Comment: Автор вопроса отправляет данные тела в [JSON](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1253237/отправка-данных-json-api-на-серверjs-php#comment2201545_1253237), а пытается извлечь их из $_POST.

Comment: @НикитаБаканин добавил ссылку - почитайте. Лучше всего использовать pdo c prepared statement, но они тоже есть и в mysqli обычном.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov извините за грубость, но это бред

Comment: @InDevX для чего мне защита от инъекций? У меня переменная не определена ещё в начале скрипта

Comment: @НикитаБаканин а какая разница где она определена? Вы напрямую с поста вставляете в запрос её.. Не надо так

Comment: @InDevX Переменные не могу пройти проверку, так как они пустые, и не выполняют запрос в базу данных

Comment: @НикитаБаканин ключи смените.. `$_POST['login']/$_POST['password']`